# Calculation on one row of a Data Frame with the other row for calculating returns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, finance, calculation

I have a following set of sample data which has many rows and columns. I am trying to do calculate the monthly returns. I have done it in the past using excel but cannot find a solution for this.

RETURNS = (THIS_MONTH_PRICE/PREVIOUS_MONTH_PRICE) - 1

`DF1 =` 

           `Date Price   Stock

    1   1/31/2011   339.32  AAPL
    2   2/28/2011   353.21  AAPL
    3   3/31/2011   348.45  AAPL
    4   4/29/2011   348.23  AAPL
    5   5/31/2011   347.83  AAPL
    6   6/30/2011   335.67  AAPL
    7   7/29/2011   390.48  AAPL
    8   8/31/2011   384.83  AAPL`

OUTPUT:

`DF2=`

            `Date    Price   Stock   RETURNS

    1   1/31/2011   339.32  AAPL    NA
    2   2/28/2011   353.21  AAPL    0.040934811
    3   3/31/2011   348.45  AAPL    0.040934811
    4   4/29/2011   348.23  AAPL    0.040934811
    5   5/31/2011   347.83  AAPL    0.040934811
    6   6/30/2011   335.67  AAPL    0.040934811
    7   7/29/2011   390.48  AAPL    0.16328537
    8   8/31/2011   384.83  AAPL    -0.014469371`

Can anyone help me in solving this. Thanks.

Comment: Your output looks strange to me. Why did you get a lot of `0.040934811` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `lag` function from the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(RETURNS = Price/lag(Price) - 1)

df2
#        Date  Price Stock       RETURNS
# 1 1/31/2011 339.32  AAPL            NA
# 2 2/28/2011 353.21  AAPL  0.0409348108
# 3 3/31/2011 348.45  AAPL -0.0134764021
# 4 4/29/2011 348.23  AAPL -0.0006313675
# 5 5/31/2011 347.83  AAPL -0.0011486661
# 6 6/30/2011 335.67  AAPL -0.0349596067
# 7 7/29/2011 390.48  AAPL  0.1632853696
# 8 8/31/2011 384.83  AAPL -0.0144693710
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "           Date Price   Stock
                  1   '1/31/2011'   339.32  AAPL
                  2   '2/28/2011'   353.21  AAPL
                  3   '3/31/2011'   348.45  AAPL
                  4   '4/29/2011'   348.23  AAPL
                  5   '5/31/2011'   347.83  AAPL
                  6   '6/30/2011'   335.67  AAPL
                  7   '7/29/2011'   390.48  AAPL
                  8   '8/31/2011'   384.83  AAPL",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in a solution using only base R:

```
> DF1$RETURNS <- (df$Price / c(0, head(df$Price, -1))) - 1
> DF1
       Date  Price Stock       RETURNS
1 1/31/2011 339.32  AAPL           Inf
2 2/28/2011 353.21  AAPL  0.0409348108
3 3/31/2011 348.45  AAPL -0.0134764021
4 4/29/2011 348.23  AAPL -0.0006313675
5 5/31/2011 347.83  AAPL -0.0011486661
6 6/30/2011 335.67  AAPL -0.0349596067
7 7/29/2011 390.48  AAPL  0.1632853696
8 8/31/2011 384.83  AAPL -0.0144693710
```